# NSTextView, where is it coming from when using NSSearchField and NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, nssearchfield

Where does NSTextView come from?

In my OSX application i have a NSSearchField, i implemented `controlTextDidChange:` which contains in key `NSFieldEditor` a `NSTextView` instance

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {

    NSTextView * searchField = note.userInfo[@"NSFieldEditor"];
    ...
}
```

also when asking

```
id firstResponder = [self.window firstResponder];
```

i get a `NSTextView`

But where is it coming from??? **as `NSSearchField` nor `NSTextField` is NOT derived from NSTextView... also not it's cell... also i cannot find a property for it in NSSearchField**

I'am using NSSearchField for sure

[image]

also when connecting the action outlet to `NSSearchField`, the sender is `NSSearchField` (which is ok)

```
- (IBAction)searchFieldCommit:(NSSearchField *)sender {
   //...
}
```

**What is this mess, why do i get `NSSearchField` vs `NSTextView` and how to access the `NSSearchField` from `NSTextView` and vice versa**

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa maintains a shared NSTextView called the "field editor". It is described in more detail here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html

Answer (score 1):

Aderstedt is right about the field editor.  The other thing you need to know is that in your `controlTextDidChange:` method, `note.object` will be the control that sent the notification.